# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hidden' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I want `["2","2","2"]` from `{1:2,  10:2,  15:2 }` since chart.js is unable to pick co-ordinates from an object

Comment: Hi Sam, please show us your code and provide more detail about the issue you're facing. Also please explain your desired output. Otherwise it's impossible to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Object.values()** and **.map()** to achieve this

```
const data = {1:2, 10:2, 15:2 } 

const result = Object.values(data).map(v => v.toString());

console.log(result); // [ '2', '2', '2' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get all the values into an array from the object. Then use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert those values from *Number* to *String*:

```js
var o = {1:2, 10:2, 15:2 };
var output = Object.values(o).map(n => n.toString())
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop though the object and put the values in an array.

```js
let object = { 1: 2, 10: 2, 15: 2 };
let array = []

for (let key in object) {
    array.push(object[key])
}

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log (Object.values ({1:2, 10:2, 15:2 }).map (v => v.toString ()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Below solution may helps for you'

```
let chartData = {1:2, 10:2, 15:2 };
let finalChartData = [];
for (var keyValenter code here in chartData) {
 finalChartData.push(chartData[keyVal]);
}
console.log(finalChartData);


In the above solution you will pass "finalChartData" variable as chart data.
```